# Pass string variable parameter node.js not express

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

I was wondering how you would use node.js to parse a string parameter from a request url akin to express.
I know this is possible with express, but I would like to know how it can be done with node.js without express.

Express example:

```
var app = require('express')(); 
app.get('sample/request/url/:id', function(req, res) { 
  var parameter = req.params.id;
});
```

Comment: When it comes to parsing URL params, Express is doing all of the heavy lifting here. You should look into using the [Query String](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) module to create a similar mechanism.

Comment: Check out [`paramify`](https://github.com/hij1nx/paramify).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are using [`connect`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) (or just [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) module) you can use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

- With [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html):

  ```
  var http = require('http');

  http.createServer(function (req, res) { // Note there's no next here
      var match = req.url.match(/^sample\/request\/url\/(.+)$/);
      var id = match ? match[1] : null;
  }).listen(3000);

  ...
  ```
- With [`connect`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect):

  ```
  var connect = require('connect');

  connect.createServer(funcion(req, res, next) {
      var match = req.url.match(/^sample\/request\/url\/(.+)$/);
      var id = match ? match[1] : null;
  }).listen(3000);

  ...
  ```

This is the simple case. If you want to have your own routing middleware you should start with an array of `RegExps` (that can be generated dinamically from a `String` that you add) and loop through them until you find a match.

Each route element should have its `RegExp` and also its parameters, so that once you find a match you can extract and append the parameters to the `req` object with an appropriate name that you choose.

**EDIT:**

As [robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep) pointed out in his comment, you can check [`paramify`](https://github.com/hij1nx/paramify). Its [code](https://github.com/hij1nx/paramify/blob/master/index.js) is very clear and does some of the things I said in the last part of the answer. For example, you can see it has a function `regify` to dinamically contruct the `RegExps` and a loop to extract the parameters of a match:

```
var params = []

for (var i = 1; i < matches.length; i++) {
    var key = reg.keys[i - 1]
    if (key) {
        params[key.name] = matches[i]
    } else {
        params.push(matches[i])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `url` property from `req` and parse as you want:

```
var server = require('http').createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.url);
  // would log "/sample/request/url/123"
});
```

The parse part can be done using [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).